# Check if document exist by an array of IDs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to return array of IDs if document with that ID doesn't exists.

Schema is:

```
{
 id: Number,
 ...
}
```

And I have an Array:

```
let queryArr = [id1, id2, ...]
```

For example, I have this collection:

```
{
 id: 1
},
{
 id: 2
},
{
 id: 3
}
```

And `queryArr` is `[1,2,3,4,5]`

So, output will be `[4,5]`

Basically, I'm putting array to query something like this:

```
db.collection.find({
 id: queryArr               //IDK what to do here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Also see [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)

```
db.collection.find({
  id: {
    $nin: [
      4,
      5
    ]
  }
})
```

This  will return the following data

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "id": 3
  }
]
```

or you can use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) ,to get the documents which have ids included in array

```
db.collection.find({
      id: {
        $in: [
          4,
          5
        ]
      }
    })
```

See [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mML1FfL5gJW)

Comment: `$in` method looks nice, but I'll put all queryArr which is `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Is there any way to get those IDs, which doesn't exists? 4 and 5 in my case.

Comment: how you are supoosed to get the data back if it is not in the daatabase?

Comment: I don't need data, just IDs of documents, that doesn't exists

Comment: but how if those ids doesn't even exists in db ,how you can get that even?

Comment: That's a point of the question. Find out which documents are missing.

Comment: That's not possible,getting the ids which are not even present in db .